# how to check radio buttons programatically when the scanned qr match with text in the listview

Tags: java, android, listview, barcode-scanner

I am developing attendance system and i have a listview with students name i want  to programatically check or uncheck the radio buttons in the listview when the scanned qr matchs the student name I tried to do it in the ontextchengeListner method of txtresult but the text is changing many time even in reading a single qr

This are my java classes

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.attendance.olana.qr_scanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by olana on 23/03/2018.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] questionsList;
    public static String message;
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    public static TextView question ;
    public static RadioButton yes,no ;
    public static ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] questionsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.questionsList = questionsList;
// initialize arraylist and add static string for all the questions
        selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {
            selectedAnswers.add("Not Attempted");
        }
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questionsList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
// get the reference of TextView and Button's
         question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question);
       yes = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.yes);
       no = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.no);




// perform setOnCheckedChangeListener event on yes button
        yes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
// set Yes values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
                if (isChecked)
                    selectedAnswers.set(i, "Present");
            }
        });
// perform setOnCheckedChangeListener event on no button
        no.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
// set No values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
                if (isChecked)
                    selectedAnswers.set(i, "Absent");

            }
        });
// set the value in TextView
        question.setText(questionsList[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

list.java

```
package com.attendance.olana.qr_scanner;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by olana on 23/03/2018.
 */
public class list extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView simpleList;
    public static String[] questions;
    Button submit,scan;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        scan =(Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);

// get the string array from string.xml file
        questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.student);
// get the reference of ListView and Button
        simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
// set the adapter to fill the data in the ListView
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), questions);
        simpleList.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(list.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
// perform setOnClickListerner event on Button
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = "";
// get the value of selected answers from custom adapter
                for (int i = 0; i < CustomAdapter.selectedAnswers.size(); i++) {
                    message = message + "\n" + (i + 1) + " " + CustomAdapter.selectedAnswers.get(i);
                }
// display the message on screen with the help of Toast.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.attendance.olana.qr_scanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    SurfaceView camerapreview;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    TextView txtresult;
    String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);
        //Button scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);



        finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        camerapreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        txtresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtresult);
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .build();

        //add event
        camerapreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


                try {
                    cameraSource.start(camerapreview.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                cameraSource.stop();

            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(camerapreview.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                if (qrcodes.size() != 0) {
                    txtresult.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //create vibration
                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(100);
                            txtresult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);


                            //barcodeDetector.release();


                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Please tell me where i can implement these the programatically checking or unchecking the radio button when the name in the listview matchs the scanned qr please help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Because a qr code contains multiple characters of data, the text changed event gets triggered multiple times, one per character.

Comment: @ADm i think my question is very specific ....what i want is to check or uncheck radio button inside listview when the scanned qr match with the text in the list ...i think it is now clear